# Solving CS0029 when returning a viewresult after async task

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I get a [CS0029](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0029) error when I try to return a view using the data that have been recieved from MongoDb.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<RecommendationModel> Get(string id)
{
    return View ("RecommendationDetails", await _recommendationRepository.GetRecommendation(id));
}
```

When I just return the `await` (see below), I get a correct JSON result.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<RecommendationModel> Get(string id)
{
    return await _recommendationRepository.GetRecommendation(id));
}
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Returning [`View()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnetcore-2.1) from a controller action returns a [`ViewResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewresult?view=aspnetcore-2.0) which is an [`IActionResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iactionresult?view=aspnetcore-2.0). So you should have your method return a `Task<IActionResult>`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
{
    var model = await _recommendationRepository.GetRecommendation(id);
    return View("RecommendationDetails", model);
}
```

This is different from returning a model directly which causes the MVC framework to return your model directly as a JSON. But here, you want to actually invoke your Razor view and you just *pass* the model to the view for it to be rendered in some way.